# Performance degradation when using mmap

Tags: c++, linux, performance, mmap

I have to compute a huge nxn matrix (n > 100000) and somehow store it in memory for further usage. Computation of a single element is quite expensive ( a few 1000 flops and memory accesses) and so I can't compute it on the fly. However I only need to compute it once and do not need to modify it later. I also can't assume that I have enough swap space on the system. That's why i decided to create a cache file and use mmap to map it to memory:

```
int createCacheFile(std::size_t filesize, std::string const& filename){
    //create empty file
    int fileDescriptor = open(filename.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, (mode_t)0600);
    //stretch to desired size
    lseek(fileDescriptor, filesize-1, SEEK_SET);
    return fileDescriptor;
}

//...
std::size_t n = 100000;
std::size_t fileSize = n*n*sizeof(float);
int fileDescriptor = createCacheFile(filesize,"matrix.cache");
float* memory = (float*) mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fileDescriptor, 0);

//and now fill it...
```

I wanted to compare performance and tried a small n=10000 and compared malloc, mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS and the above implementation. For this n the matrix fits completely into RAM. While malloc and MAP_ANONYMOUS give quite similar results, I get a roughly factor 10 penalty when computing my matrix when it is backed by a file. It seems that the program is regularly stopped by the kernel so that it can write the contents safely to the file. I tried to resolve this using msync and mprotect on the parts of the matrix that i have already computed to give the kernel a hint that it can write the sections without having to stop the programs but nothing helped.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You need to [tune the VM](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-kernel-tuning-virtual-memory-subsystem/) to not block your process even when there's lots of dirty pages in memory that need to be written.

Comment: would creating the file in RAM solve the issue?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz great! I did not know these settings. Thanks! I now changed dirty_background_ratio to 5 and dirty_ratio to 80. Is there more I can do to help aside from using a SSD to speed up writing? Does it help to tell msync that it can write the first k pages as a continuous block? Or will the kernel figure that out by itself?

Comment: BTW, RAM is often cheap these days. Did you consider buying some more?

Comment: The number of server mainboards that can support a terrabyte of RAM is rather limited. I would like to set Davids answer as the solution to my question. But I can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) syscall to inform the kernel about less useful pages (perhaps with `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` or `MADV_DONTNEED` ...). Perhaps the [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) syscall might be helpful for the file segment. Eventually [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) (in another thread, since it is blocking) might help also.

And the file might sit in a fast filesystem, perhaps a `tmpfs` one....

Perhaps swapping on a fast disk (SSD) might also be useful. [swapon(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/swapon.2.html) syscall (and `swapon` command).